# How to place an image over an image when radio button is checked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4-5 radio buttons with an image below each. I would like to change the image to another image as the button is checked. I can do it by 4 if else if to check what is selected and then place the image over that image but I would like to do it with a few lines as its same image for all radio buttons. I started this:

**CSS**

```
#selectedRadio {
        display:none;
        width:74px;
        height:69px;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:20px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("input[name=choose]").change(function(){          
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                jQuery("#selectedRadio").slideDown()
            }                                                       
       });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="selectedRadio"><img src="selected.png" /></div>
<input name="choose"  value="black"> <br><img src ="black.jpg" />
<input name="choose"  value="white"> <br><img src ="white.jpg" />
<input name="choose"  value="red"> <br><img src ="red.jpg" />
<input name="choose"  value="blue"> <br><img src ="blue.jpg" />
```

Comment: Please post valid html

Comment: @Jay, you code is a mess and not valid.  Very little is clear.

Comment: @Jay, is what you want for 'selected.png' to replace each image associated with the input clicked?  Can only one be selected at a time?

Comment: yes, each raido has an image, all i want is to show an image over that image when its selected. Like a tick mark showing it's selected.

Comment: does the selected image replace the original image or sit on top of it creating a layered effect?  if the former, my answer below does what you want; if the latter, I need to change my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created [a fiddle that shows one way of doing this](http://jsfiddle.net/TA38u/1/).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="black"/>
        <img src="black.jpg" alt="black image" data-color="black" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="white"/>
        <img src="white.jpg" alt="white image" data-color="white" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="red"/>
        <img src="red.jpg" alt="red image" data-color="red" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choose" value="blue"/>
        <img src="blue.jpg" alt="blue image" data-color="blue" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('label').click(function () {
        var that = this,
            images = $(this).closest('div.container').find('img');
        images.each(function () {
            var t = $(this);
            if (t.data('color') === $(that).find('input').val()) {
                t.attr({
                    src: 'selected.png',
                    alt: 'selected image'
                });
            } else {
                t.attr({
                    src: t.data('color') + '.jpg',
                    alt: t.data('color') + ' image'
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And some basic styling:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
input,
img {
    display: block;
}
```

Again, this is just one possible way of doing it, to get the concept across.

Comment: thank you, this one is near to what I wanted..I actually wanted to put that selected.png over the current image so that its like "tick mark" over the "color". Another issue is, when I copy your code and do it, the previous selection doesn't reset, i will fix this as it doesn't happen on js fiddle.

Comment: I can create a version with the overlay if you want.  Some of the same principles apply.

Comment: If you can post the url of the actual images you're using, I could use them in my fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

maybe use the hide() / show() methods?
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: you mean hide / show for each button selected? I am trying to avoid several if and else as  the options will increase from 4 to 20 or so.

Comment: you just want as little lines as possible?